# How to run a Talend job from inside a java application

Tags: java, talend

I created a Talend Open Studio Job and would like to run it with arguments from inside a java application. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to export the job as a `standalone job`. You can follow the tutorial provided by TalendForge http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?idTuto=17#s10

After the export you will obtain a `jar` file per job.

Answer (score 1):

Talend Studio allows you to export a job and to call it from external Java applications.
This link explains how to call a Talend job from a Java program using the Eclipse IDE:

<strike>https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Calling+a+Talend+Job+from+an+external+Java+application</strike>

[Calling a Talend Job from an external Java application](https://help.talend.com/reader/uN~DBojHtRraw~1IihuCzw/LmOR5l7nkrngW_F8T6VaEg)